# T SQL Query to get result when no rows returned

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

this is the query

```
SELECT NAME,DATE, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
FROM STG
WHERE 
DATE='2018-04-23' AND 
NAME='DRAFT'
GROUP BY NAME,DATE
```

Requirement is if the query returns no rows then I should get output as 'TEST','TODAY'S DATE', 0 
else if query return rows then the normal output which is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one method uses `union all`:

```
with t as (
      SELECT NAME, DATE, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT 
      FROM STG
      WHERE DATE = '2018-04-23' AND NAME = 'DRAFT'
      GROUP BY NAME, DATE
     )
select *
from t
union all
select name, date, row_count
from (select 'TEST' as name, getdate() as date, 0 as row_count) x
where not exists (select 1 from t);
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response and help it worked perfectly!!